# Difference between `[key: string]` and `[key in string]` in TypeScript index signatures

Tags: typescript

Consider there following examples that use `:`and `in` to define index signatures:

```
interface Colon {
  [key : string]: number;
}

interface ColonOpt {
  [key : string]?: number; // does not compile
}

interface In {
  [key in string]: number; // does not compile
}

interface InNested {
  a: {
    [key in string]: number;
  };
}

interface InNestedOpt {
  a: {
    [key in string]?: number;
  };
}
```

I am a bit confused why some compile and some don't. What's the difference of using `in` vs `:` in index signatures?

Comment: For [`in`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-the-in-operator), you're creating [mapped types](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types), which doesn't make a lot of sense with `[key in string]`.